# MPE (Most Probable Explanation) vs. MAP (Maximum A Posteriori)

Tags: machine-learning, metric

What is MPE?

How do MPE and MAP differ? Any example of when they would produce different results?

Answer (score 0):

1. What is MPE?

Ans=> MPE in machine learning stands for Maximum Posterior Estimation. It's a method used to find the most likely set of values for all variables in a model, given some observed data. This means it tries to figure out what combination of variable settings is most probable after taking into account both the data we've seen and any prior knowledge or assumptions we have about how those variables behave.

2. How do MPE and MAP differ?

Ans=> Let's imagine you and your friends are playing a game of guessing the color of marbles in a bag without looking.

MAP is like trying to guess the color of one marble based on what most people have guessed before (prior knowledge) and also considering how many times each color has been drawn from the bag so far (observed data). So if more red marbles were pulled out than any other colors, MAP would predict that the next marble will be red.

MPE, however, tries to guess all remaining colors in the bag at once. It considers not only which individual colors came up often but also combinations - for example, it might notice that after pulling two blue marbles usually comes a green one.

So while both methods use prior guesses and current observations to make predictions: MAP focuses on predicting just next outcome; MPE tries to figure out whole sequence.